# How to retrieve the ids from the array of objects using python and django?

Tags: python, django

Hi i have an array of objects like below,

```
"output": [
  {
      'id': 1,
      'items': [
          {
              'id':'1',
              'data': {
                  'id': 3,
              }
          },
          {
              'id': '2',
              'data': {
                  'id': 4,
              }
          }
      ]
  },

  {
       'id': 2,
       'items': [
           {
               'id':'3',
               'data': {
                   'id': 5,
               }
           }, 
       ]
   },
]
```

I want to retrieve the id property of items array and put it an array so the expected output is ['1','2','3']

below code works in javascript
arr_obj.map(obj=>obj.items.map(item=>item.id)).flat()

how can i do the above in python and django. could someone help me with this. I am new to python and django thanks.

**Edit:**
An example of how the logging the data in console looks.

output '[{'id': 1,'items': [{'id': 14, 'data': {'id': 1,}],}]'

Comment: The array of objects you show is javascript, not Python. How does the data looks like in the Python side

Comment: it is a json. when i log it in console i see it like that

Comment: @DaniMesejo: no this is valid Python. It is not JSON since JSON needs double quotes for strings.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Since when Python have a const?

Comment: @stackuser: why are 4 and 5 not valid items?

Comment: @DaniMesejo: where do you see a `const`? If you open a Python shell you can paste the data and it will print `[{'id': 1, 'items': [{'id': '1', 'data': {'id': 3}}, {'id': '2', 'data': {'id': 4}}]}, {'id': 2, 'items': [{'id': '3', 'data': {'id': 5}}]}]`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem See the edits of the question, now is meaningless

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: i dont want ids within data object. interested only ids within items array of object. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with list comprehension:

```
>>> [i['id'] for d in data for i in d['items']]
['1', '2', '3']
```

where `data` is the list of dictionaries.

Comment: thanks. will the above save the ids in array?

Comment: @stackuser: it returns a *list* of *strings* where the strings contain the ids (the result is printed on the second line).

Comment: thanks shall check if it works for me and accept the answer soon

Comment: @stackuser: the `>>>` is not part of the expression, that is simply the prompt of the Python shell.

Comment: for some reason its not working. i have edited question to show the data i see on console.

Comment: @stackuser: It is thus wrapped in a dictionary with as key `"output"`?

Comment: @stackuser: in that case it is `[i['id'] for d in data['output'] for i in d['items']]`

Comment: thanks shall try that and get back

Comment: i am typeerror TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @stackuser: exactly what does `data` contains? The `output` key? or the list associated with the `output` key.

Comment: sorry as i am new to python and programming i am unclear of this. but logging to console i see data like in edit section of the question (i  updated it now)

Comment: @stackuser: so if you write `print(data)` you get `[{'id': 1,'items': [{'id': 14, 'data': {'id': 1,}],}]`?

Comment: yes i see that and before that output too

Comment: @stackuser: so then it is `{ output:  [{'id': 1,'items': [{'id': 14, 'data': {'id': 1,}],}]}`? Can you please specify what you see when you `print(data)`?

Comment: i dont see curly braces before output and also it is like this output  '[{'id': 1,'items': [{'id': 14, 'data': {'id': 1,}],}]'     encapsulated in quotes

Comment: @stackuser: exactly where does `data` originates from. It looks like you converted it to a string. Can you edit the question and share the logic that constructed the data?